# PrependChild() function in angular2

Tags: angular

Is there any in-built function in angular 2+ to prepend a child element?

```
nativeElement.appendChild(xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to elaborate you question as to what is the use case that you want to use this type of thing in Angular. There must some more elegant way in Angular to handle such a situation and may be you are in the wrong direction.

You can use `*ngIf` structural directive to add and remove an element in the DOM on a certain condition.

Comment: this is regarding tabbing, when dialog(i.e a popup) opens ,it gets appended to body, because of this is when focus is on urlbar, and we press tab to bring focus on dialog it goes to background of dialog, since dialog is the last element in DOM, we want the tab to shift focus on dialog.. not the background elements. so I want to prepend my popup element to body not append.

Comment: basically i want to prepend a dynamically generated content to body.